# Sharing variable data back and forth between scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have one script calling COINS getting `coins` every time an object collides.  I want to take `coins` and  move the data into another script called SHOP.  In SHOP I want to modify the money, for example subtract it.  Then transfer that data back to COINS.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do in Unity.

You need to reference the scripts which can be done with public variables :

```cs
public class Shop : Monobehaviour {

  public Coins coins;

}

// ---

public class Coins : Monobehaviour {
  int totalCoins;
}
```

Then you can use the editor to drag the scripts into the variables. Careful though, you can not (in this case) drag the script from the project files. You must use the one attached to your gameobject.

Then if you wanted the `Shop` to subtract coins all you would have to do is use that reference of the `Coins` script variable.

```
public class Shop : Monobehaviour {

  public Coins coins;

  public void SubtractCoins(int toSub) {
    coins.totalCoins -= toSub;
  }

}
```

If your variables are public it's really easy. That's how you can start out having scripts "communicate" with each other.